# How to index my rows in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

and the following code:

```
declare @string nvarchar(max) = 'aaa,1.3,1,bbb,1.5,ccc,2.0,1'
;WITH AllItems as
(
    SELECT Item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null)) as rn
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@string, ',')
)
, Strings as
(
    SELECT Item as Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null))  as rn
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@string, ',')
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Item) = 0
), Doubles as 
( 
    SELECT Item as Measure, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null))  as rn
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@string, ',')
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Item) = 1 AND CHARINDEX('.', Item) > 0
), Integers as
(
    SELECT Item as Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null))  as rn
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@string, ',')
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Item) = 1 AND CHARINDEX('.', Item) = 0 
)

SELECT Name,  Measure, Value
FROM AllItems A
LEFT JOIN Strings S ON A.rn = S.rn
LEFT JOIN Doubles D ON A.rn = D.rn
LEFT JOIN Integers I ON A.rn = I.rn
WHERE COALESCE(Name,  Measure, Value) IS NOT NULL
```

In this code we got a `@string = 'aaa,1.3,1,bbb,1.5,ccc,2.0,1'` that returns the chars in a row named `Name` ,returns the double values in a row named `Measure` and the int values in a row named `Value`,the problem is that in my string i have always a `Name and Measure` but sometimes the `Value` is missing and I would like to place a NULL value in that space.

So in my example I shouldhave something like

```
Name       Measure  Value
---------+--------+-------
aaa        1.3       1
bbb        1.5       NULL
ccc        2.0       1
```

Instead I have :

```
Name       Measure  Value
---------+--------+-------
aaa        1.3       1
bbb        1.5       1
ccc        2.0       NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest that you modify the function to return the item number.  However, that is not necessary because your `row_number()` does that.

Then, I assume that a "missing value" means ",,".

If so, I would suggest defining the CTEs as:

```
WITH AllItems as (
      SELECT Item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select null)) as rn
      FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@string, ',')
     ),
     Strings as (
      SELECT Item as Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select null))  as rn
      FROM AllItems ai
      WHERE ai.rn % 3 = 1
     ),
     Doubles as ( 
      SELECT Item as Measure, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select null))  as rn
      FROM AllItems ai
      WHERE ai.rn % 3 = 2
     ),
     Integers as (
      SELECT Item as Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null))  as rn
      FROM AllItems ai
      WHERE ai.rn % 3 = 0
    )
. . .
```

Comment: and if you don't mind me for asking this,do you know how should I do for example lets say we got the `string = 'aaa,2,1'` the 2 is still a Measure and it will treat it as a value how should I approach this?

Comment: @JohnPietrar . . . I don't think that encoding values in strings in a good idea.  There are many ways to encode data in strings, such as XML and JSON.  Fix the code that writes the value to something unambiguous.

Comment: a problem is that this way it find the null value and the rest of the table is random so in the example given by me `@string = 'aaa,1.3,1,bbb,1.5,ccc,2.0,1'` it will do `Name = aaa | bbb | 2.0 ;Measure =  1.3 | 1.5 | 1; Value = 1 | ccc | NULL` while it should be `Name = aaa | bbb | ccc ;Measure =  1.3 | 1.5 | 2.0; Value = 1 | NULL| 1` and that is because the missing value is not `,,` ,its just not there as you can see after `bbb,1.5` there should be a value also that is missing.